# React Router v4: Animated transition jumps down

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reactcsstransitiongroup

I try to setup fade-in fade-out transition between routed components using RR4 and ReactCSSTransitionGroup based on example from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions

Animations work, however previous component jumps down before next one is rendered.

What am I doing wrong and is there an easier way to transition between multiple components (without using parametrized paths, using react-motion instead of CSSTransitionGroup)?

screencast:

https://media.giphy.com/media/l4FGnVfAgiX4Hzns4/giphy.gif

code:

**AnimatedTrans.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import {MemoryRouter as Router, Redirect, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

import s from './AnimatedTrans.css';

const DisplayParam = ({match: {params}}) => (
    <div>param is: {params.pname} count is {params.count}</div>
);


const AnimatedTrans = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route render={({location}) => (
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/"
                       render={() => (<Redirect to='/home/0' />)} />
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/home/1">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about/2">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/contact/3">Contact</Link></li>
                </ul>
                <div className={s.el}>
                    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
                        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
                        transitionLeaveTimeout={200}
                        transitionName={{
                            enter: s.enter,
                            enterActive: s.eactive,
                            leave: s.leave,
                            leaveActive: s.lactive,
                        }}>
                        <Route location={location}
                               key={location.key}
                               path="/:pname/:count"
                               component={DisplayParam}
                        />
                    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
                </div>
            </div>
        )} />
    </Router>
);

export default AnimatedTrans;
```

**AnimatedTrans.css**.

```
.el {
    position: absolute;
}

.enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.2s;
}
.eactive {
    opacity: 1;
}

.leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}

.lactive {
    opacity: 0.01;
}
```

Comment: I been trying to do something similar, but I have not had any success due to my lack of understanding react. Do you have a small example of route component transitions with the same code. I have recreated your example [router transitions](http://codepen.io/w9914420/pen/YVZEmp?editors=0110) also I noticed that if you double clicked the button you replay the same transition ideally you do not want this to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the feeling that you gave the `absolute` css property to the wrong div.
Instead of giving it to the `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup/>` parent div, try to give it to the children (and put the parent position as `relative`).

Comment: I can confirm that this works see my pen: [params transition](http://codepen.io/w9914420/pen/YVZEmp?editors=0110)